# '[ResponseData]' to expected argument type 'ResponseData'

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm creating an application which are fetching data from an API. I've created the "API call" in a separate class so I can use the same call multiple times. But it does not return the value as I expect it to.

**In ViewController A**

```
    let data = JsonData.init()
    data.downloadJsonData(urlString: urlString) { (responseArray) in
        dataArray.append(responseArray)
        print(self.dataArray)
    }
```

I'm getting the error at `dataArray.append(responseArray)`:

> Cannot convert value of type '[ResponseData]' to expected argument type 'ResponseData'

**In JsonData class**

```
class JsonData{
    var dataArray:[ResponseData] = []

    func downloadJsonData(urlString: String, completed: @escaping (Array<ResponseData>) -> ()){

        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else{
                return
            }
            do{
                self.dataArray = [try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)]

                //Complete task in background
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed(self.dataArray)
                }
            }
            catch let jsonErr{
                print(jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I assume the problem is at:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    completed(self.dataArray)
}
```

So I would like to return the array back to the correct class once it fetched the data from the API. What could I have done wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear: You are using the (wrong) API for appending a single element

Replace

```
dataArray.append(responseArray)
```

with

```
self.dataArray.append(contentsOf: responseArray)
```

Side note:

Setting and later appending the items again makes no sense. Use a local variable.

Replace

```
self.dataArray = [try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)]

    //Complete task in background
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completed(self.dataArray)
    }
```

with (a different name makes it clearer)

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)

    //Complete task in background
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         completed([result])
    }
```

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly fine.

How do you mean with "You are using the (wrong) API to append a single element"?

Comment: Damn, I just realized the error... I used .append instead of replacing it.. Ofcourse I need to use the (contentsOf:), thanks a lot for your input!